# How to dispatch tasks in Linux when the system is not busy

Tags: linux, multithreading, bash, shell, unix

I'm using a 12 core 24 thread Linux machine to performing the following task. Each task is independent.

```
while read parameter
do
    ./program_a $parameter $parameter.log 2>&1 &
done < parameter_file
```

However this code will dispatch all the tasks at one time, which could read to serious context switch lack of idle cpu power and/or lack of memory.

I want to exploit system information tools such as **free**, **top**, and **ps** to determine if the task should be dispatched.

Using **free**.

```
while read parameter
do
    #for instance using free
    free_mem=`free -g | grep Mem | awk '{print $4}'`
    if [ $free_mem -gt 10]; then
        ./program_a $parameter $parameter.log 2>&1 &
    fi
done < parameter_file
```

But this won't work because this won't wait until the condition meet the criteria. How should I do this?

Besides how should I use **top** and **ps** to determine if the system is busy or not. I want to dispatch new task when the system is too busy.

Maybe I can use

```
ps aux | grep "program_a " | grep -v "grep" | wc -l
```

to limit the number of dispatched tasks. But it is a implicit way to determine if the system is busy or not. Any other thought?

Comment: Sounds like a good job for GNU [parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) or similar...

Answer (score 1):

```
while read parameter
do
    #for instance using free
    while 1; do
      free_mem=`free -g | awk '/Mem/{print $4}'`
      if (( $free_mem > 10 )); then
        break
      fi
      sleep 1 # wait so that some tasks might finish
    done
    ./program_a $parameter $parameter.log 2>&1 &    
done < parameter_file
```

Comment: The grep is surplus.  Instead use /Mem/ before the print in awk: `free_mem=$(free -g | awk '/Mem/{print $4}')` and also `$free_mem < 10` should be `$free_mem > 10`

Comment: @jwpat7 Feel free to edit my post. I just took his code and added the busy wait.